# Bootstrap 3 responsive images side by side same height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to use 2 responsive images side by side with same height with [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/)? At the moment the `col-sm-4` hasn't the same height.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">                                     
        <div class="col-sm-4">                 
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" />
        </div>                  
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" />
        </div>                  
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/u9av6/3/

Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've forgot to add the container. http://jsfiddle.net/u9av6/3/

Comment: Added =) Although for future reference, you are able to edit the question after it's posted!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" height="220" /></div>

<div class="col-sm-8"><img src="http://placehold.it/800x400" height="220" /></div>
```

Comment: this is responsive: style="max-height:220px"

Comment: What if the image has the height smaller than 220px?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working version, with [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MkP88/).

```
<div class="col-sm-4"><img style="max-height:220px" src="http://placehold.it/400x400" /></div>                       
<div class="col-sm-8"><img style="max-height:220px" src="http://placehold.it/800x400" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem is that in your code, the padding is not considering.

Your `400px` and `800px` is nice, but with padding considering it's not good.

In this fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/Lrc5t/1/ , with no padding, they keep the same height. But it's not nice without padding...

The padding in each `.row` is `15px` left and right.

**html:**

```
<div class="row">                   
    <div class="col-sm-4 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>                       
    <div class="col-sm-8 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x400"></div>              
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.nopadding{
    padding-left: 0px !important;
    padding-right:0px !important;    
}
```

**UPDATE :**

**fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/Lrc5t/2/

Without paddding is not nice so , just inverse in adding extra padding to right image :

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x400"></div>

<div class="col-sm-8 nopadding-two"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x400"></div>

</div>

.nopadding-two{
    padding-right:45px !important;
}
```

**ps** : You can choose to add your padding at left instead or right... in order to keep the padding in middle. And... `nopadding-one` and `text-right` class are to delete...(I forgot)...

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT:**
****Why 45px ?****
*Image 1 is float:left so it has just the padding-right at 15px
Image 2 has padding left and right at 15px {=30px}
So in order do equality (to get same constraints) you need to transmit the total padding to image 2*

Comment: Yes, with the nopadding class it looks fine. But without padding is not so good ... :(

Comment: Sorry, last question. Would it possible to set the padding to 30px? I think it will only work with 45px?

Comment: @l00per I try to explain in updating my answer... It's not clear but I don't find better, excuse me...

Comment: Thank you! So I think it's not possible to set the padding between left and right image to 10px, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

To make the images displaying side by side, you need to do three things:

**1st**: make all your images responsive in the html file like this:

```
<div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-3 left-image"  >

        <img  class="img-responsive" src="../img/fourthimg.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 right-image">

          <img class="img-responsive" src="../img/firstimg.jpg" >

     </div>

    </div>
```

This is for putting two images side by side. You could have as many images as possible.

**2nd:** Inside your css, give the height to these images like this:

```
   .img-responsive {display:block; height: 600px; width: 100%;}
```

The width is set to 100% meaning that both (for this example)/all the images would cover the 100% part of the column width provided in your html code.

**3rd (Most important) :** CSS has this property to automatically leave margins/paddings on right and left when you put an image inside a div and this padding is associated with the image or any other element that you want to put inside a div.

To tackle this, go to you css file and for each image, set the left-padding and right padding to 0px just like this:

```
.right-image{
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;

}


.left-image{

 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;


}
```

This is a working example and explanation of how to put in images side by side using bootstrap!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. This code will look for the smallest height of the image and set it as max-height of the other images. The rest of the image will be hidden. Check it out.

```
<script>
   setTimeout(function () {
      equalheight('.portfolio-item');
   }, 3000);
   function equalheight($that) {
      $minHeight = 0;
      $($that).each(function (index) {
         $thisHeight = $(this).children('.portfolio-link').innerHeight();
         if ($minHeight == 0) {
            $minHeight = $thisHeight;
         } else {
            if ($minHeight > $thisHeight) {
               $minHeight = $thisHeight;
            }
         }
      });
      $($that).children('.portfolio-link').css('max-height', $minHeight);
      $($that).children('.portfolio-link').css('overflow', 'hidden');
   }
</script>
```

My html is

```
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#portfolioModal1" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" style="max-height: 225px; overflow: hidden;">
                     <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                           <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <img src="images/trip-01.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <div class="portfolio-caption">
                     <h4>Round Icons</h4>
                     <p class="text-muted">Graphic Design</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                  <a href="#portfolioModal2" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" style="max-height: 225px; overflow: hidden;">
                     <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                           <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <img src="images/trip-02.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                  </a>
                  <div class="portfolio-caption">
                     <h4>Startup Framework</h4>
                     <p class="text-muted">Website Design</p>
                  </div>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want constant height, should add these properties:

```
height: 200x ;   # any constant height
object-fit: cover;
```

Or else you want width constant, should add these properties:

```
width: 200px ;  # any constant height
object-fit: cover;
```

object-fit: cover, fixed the problem of stretching up of the image in my case.